# Xcode 4 Scheme Hell?

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode4, ios5

I have a serious ongoing issue with Xcode 4. I have been using Xcode 3 for years, and had everything set up perfectly. All my Build Configurations worked A-OK.

I updated to iOS 5 GM, and naturally I have to use Xcode 4 to submit my app to the Store or use TestFlight. I can't change my Build Configuration. I've tried making a new "Scheme" (which are stupid IMHO, when the old system worked 100%), and everytime I do, I set everything the same, I go "Product" > "Archive"....it works, and I share the IPA to my Desktop, to upload it to TestFlight, or I save it as a ZIP and send it to Application Loader.

IT NEVER WORKS. On TestFlight, my testers will install it, and immediately the application will crash. It won't even launch, no matter how I build the app, regardless of Scheme. It worked 100% and I have made ZERO changes since updating to Xcode 4.

Xcode 4 only works when I wish to "Debug"  my app on my own device. It builds, installs and runs perfectly. Why won't it work on AdHoc or App Store?

PLEASE HELP! I'm ready to pull my hair out.

Comment: What do the device logs say, why does your app crash?

Comment: Nothing, It just crashes. It builds, and apparently signs it for the Ad Hoc or App Store Build Configurations that I chose in the Scheme Editor. The only "Scheme" and Build that works is Debug on my own device. :/

Comment: Fri Oct 07 17:41:29 com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.cocotutch.Muzik[0xb4ab]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: It works 100% with no issues when I Debug/Run it on my very own device. It just never works for the AppStore or Ad Hoc.

Comment: Then you should make a release build and test/debug that. You probably have a crash issue that only occurs in release builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, it was an absolutely STUPID issue!

I was checking the size of my Info.plist for any changes, and for some ridiculous reason only Apple can comprehend, updating to iOS 5 made that code obsolete. So the use of the code in my Release/AppStore/AdHoc builds was making it crash on launch. Once I commented the code out, everything is back working 100%.

Strange.

Even Apple Technical Support couldn't figure it out and they had my whole project to peruse. Apple REALLY need to improve their software when they change it. Not create a massive learning curve for their users and encourage code-cleanups if the SDK decides it doesn't like 4.3 code.